# Simple web scrape issues

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Apologies if this question is elementary, but I'm a newbie to scraping and am trying to perform a simple scrape of NFL Future prices off of a website, but am not having any luck.  My code is below.  At this point, I'm just trying to get something/anything to return (ultimately will pull the text of the team names and futures prices), but this code returns "None" and "[]" (an empty list) for the find and find_all functions, respectively.  I get the find/find_all parameters by inspecting the first line of the page (Baltimore Ravens) when I see that the team names are held in a span with the class of "style_label__2KJur".

I suspect this has something to do with how the html is loaded.  When I print(nfl_futures), I don't see any of the html that I inspected for the first line which is presumably why I get no results.  If this is true, how do I expose all of the html I need in order to scrape this data?

Appreciate the help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pinnacle.com/en/football/nfl/matchups#futures"
r = requests.get(url).content
nfl_futures = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
first_line = nfl_futures.find('span', class_="style_label__2KJur")
lines = nfl_futures.find_all('span', class_="style_label__2KJur")

print(first_line)
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
None
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: That page makes a lot of xhr requests, so you will need a way to render those js requests, there's a lot of ways to make that. You can use selenium, splash ,etc. Also, you can try to find the right requests using dev tools(F12 inc hrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is hardly a simple scrape. The page is dynamic. You could use selenium to first render the page, then grab the html to parse with bs4. Or as stated, grab the dat from the api, but then you need to do a little data manipulation to join them. I always like going the api method as it's robust and more efficient.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.pinnacle.com/config/app.json'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

x_api_key = jsonData['api']['haywire']['apiKey']
headers = {
        'X-API-Key': x_api_key}


matchups_url = "https://guest.api.arcadia.pinnacle.com/0.1/leagues/889/matchups"
jsonData_matchups = requests.get(matchups_url, headers=headers).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData_matchups, 
                       record_path = ['participants'],
                       meta = ['id','type',['special', 'category'],['special', 'description']],
                       meta_prefix = 'participants.',
                       errors='ignore')

df['id'] = df['id'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
df['participants.id'] = df['participants.id'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)

df = df.rename(columns={'id':'participantId','participants.id':'matchupId'})

df_matchups = df[df['participants.type'] == 'matchup']
df_special = df[df['participants.type'] == 'special']


straight_url = 'https://guest.api.arcadia.pinnacle.com/0.1/leagues/889/markets/straight'
jsonData_straight = requests.get(straight_url, headers=headers).json()

df_straight = pd.json_normalize(jsonData_straight, 
                       record_path = ['prices'],
                       meta = ['type', 'matchupId'],
                       errors='ignore')


df_straight['matchupId'] = df_straight['matchupId'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
df_straight['participantId'] = df_straight['participantId'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)

df_filter = df_straight[df_straight['designation'].isin(['home','away','over','under'])]
df_filter = df_filter.pivot_table(index=['matchupId', 'participantId'], 
                    columns='designation', 
                    values=['points','price']).reset_index(drop=False)
df_filter.columns = ['.'.join(x) if x[-1] != '' else x[0] for x in df_filter.columns]

nfl_futures = pd.merge(df_special, df_straight, how='left', left_on=['matchupId', 'participantId'], right_on=['matchupId', 'participantId'])
nfl_matchups = pd.merge(df_matchups, df_filter, how='left', left_on=['matchupId', 'participantId'], right_on=['matchupId', 'participantId'])
```

**Output:**

Here's what the first 5 rows of 324 rows looks like for futures:

```
print(nfl_futures.head(10).to_string())
  alignment participantId             name  order  rotation   matchupId participants.type     participants.special.category           participants.special.description  points  price designation       type
0   neutral    1326753860             Over      0    3017.0  1326753859           special               Regular Season Wins        Dallas Cowboys Regular Season Wins?     9.5    108         NaN      total
1   neutral    1326753861            Under      0    3018.0  1326753859           special               Regular Season Wins        Dallas Cowboys Regular Season Wins?     9.5   -129         NaN      total
2   neutral    1336218775  Trevor Lawrence      0    5801.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN    312         NaN  moneyline
3   neutral    1336218776    Justin Fields      0    5802.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN    461         NaN  moneyline
4   neutral    1336218777      Zach Wilson      0    5803.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN    790         NaN  moneyline
5   neutral    1336218778       Trey Lance      0    5804.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN    655         NaN  moneyline
6   neutral    1336218779        Mac Jones      0    5805.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN    807         NaN  moneyline
7   neutral    1336218780       Kyle Pitts      0    5806.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN   1095         NaN  moneyline
8   neutral    1336218781     Najee Harris      0    5807.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN   1015         NaN  moneyline
9   neutral    1336218782    DeVonta Smith      0    5808.0  1336218774           special  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year  NFL Offensive Rookie of the Year 2021-22?     NaN   1903         NaN  moneyline
```

And here is week 1 matchup lines:

```
print(nfl_matchups.to_string())
   alignment participantId                      name  order  rotation   matchupId participants.type participants.special.category participants.special.description  points.away  points.home  points.over  points.under  price.away  price.home  price.over  price.under
0       home             0      Tampa Bay Buccaneers      1       NaN  1327265167           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          6.5         -6.5         51.5          51.5       107.0      -118.0       101.0       -112.0
1       away             0            Dallas Cowboys      0       NaN  1327265167           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          6.5         -6.5         51.5          51.5       107.0      -118.0       101.0       -112.0
2       home             0  Washington Football Team      1       NaN  1327265554           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          0.0          0.0         44.5          44.5      -115.0       104.0      -106.0       -106.0
3       away             0      Los Angeles Chargers      0       NaN  1327265554           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          0.0          0.0         44.5          44.5      -115.0       104.0      -106.0       -106.0
4       home             0             Detroit Lions      1       NaN  1327265774           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -7.5          7.5         46.0          46.0       101.0      -111.0      -106.0       -106.0
5       away             0       San Francisco 49ers      0       NaN  1327265774           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -7.5          7.5         46.0          46.0       101.0      -111.0      -106.0       -106.0
6       home             0         Las Vegas Raiders      1       NaN  1327266134           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -4.5          4.5         51.0          51.0      -110.0      -100.0      -106.0       -106.0
7       away             0          Baltimore Ravens      0       NaN  1327266134           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -4.5          4.5         51.0          51.0      -110.0      -100.0      -106.0       -106.0
8       home             0          Los Angeles Rams      1       NaN  1327266054           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          7.5         -7.5         45.0          45.0      -114.0       103.0      -106.0       -106.0
9       away             0             Chicago Bears      0       NaN  1327266054           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          7.5         -7.5         45.0          45.0      -114.0       103.0      -106.0       -106.0
10      home             0        Kansas City Chiefs      1       NaN  1327265828           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          6.0         -6.0         52.5          52.5       102.0      -112.0      -106.0       -106.0
11      away             0          Cleveland Browns      0       NaN  1327265828           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          6.0         -6.0         52.5          52.5       102.0      -112.0      -106.0       -106.0
12      home             0         Carolina Panthers      1       NaN  1327265337           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          4.0         -4.0         43.0          43.0      -105.0      -105.0      -106.0       -106.0
13      away             0             New York Jets      0       NaN  1327265337           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          4.0         -4.0         43.0          43.0      -105.0      -105.0      -106.0       -106.0
14      home             0        Cincinnati Bengals      1       NaN  1327265711           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -3.5          3.5         48.0          48.0      -105.0      -105.0      -106.0       -106.0
15      away             0         Minnesota Vikings      0       NaN  1327265711           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -3.5          3.5         48.0          48.0      -105.0      -105.0      -106.0       -106.0
16      home             0        New Orleans Saints      1       NaN  1327266000           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -2.5          2.5         50.0          50.0      -118.0       107.0      -106.0       -106.0
17      away             0         Green Bay Packers      0       NaN  1327266000           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -2.5          2.5         50.0          50.0      -118.0       107.0      -106.0       -106.0
18      home             0             Buffalo Bills      1       NaN  1327265283           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          7.0         -7.0         50.0          50.0      -116.0       105.0      -106.0       -106.0
19      away             0       Pittsburgh Steelers      0       NaN  1327265283           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          7.0         -7.0         50.0          50.0      -116.0       105.0      -106.0       -106.0
20      home             0          Tennessee Titans      1       NaN  1327265444           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          3.0         -3.0         51.0          51.0      -102.0      -108.0      -116.0        104.0
21      away             0         Arizona Cardinals      0       NaN  1327265444           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          3.0         -3.0         51.0          51.0      -102.0      -108.0      -116.0        104.0
22      home             0           New York Giants      1       NaN  1327265931           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -1.0          1.0         42.5          42.5      -110.0       100.0      -106.0       -106.0
23      away             0            Denver Broncos      0       NaN  1327265931           matchup                           NaN                              NaN         -1.0          1.0         42.5          42.5      -110.0       100.0      -106.0       -106.0
24      home             0           Atlanta Falcons      1       NaN  1327265598           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          3.5         -3.5         48.0          48.0      -108.0      -102.0      -106.0       -105.0
25      away             0       Philadelphia Eagles      0       NaN  1327265598           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          3.5         -3.5         48.0          48.0      -108.0      -102.0      -106.0       -105.0
26      home             0        Indianapolis Colts      1       NaN  1327265657           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
27      away             0          Seattle Seahawks      0       NaN  1327265657           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN
28      home             0      New England Patriots      1       NaN  1327265876           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          2.5         -2.5         45.5          45.5       104.0      -115.0       103.0       -115.0
29      away             0            Miami Dolphins      0       NaN  1327265876           matchup                           NaN                              NaN          2.5         -2.5         45.5          45.5       104.0      -115.0       103.0       -115.0
```

Comment: Chitown...awesome, thank you very much.  This gives me a good bit to chew on.  I'm going to try and learn how to do it both ways (Selenium & API).  Didn't realize Pinnacle had an API.  Can I throw that "config/app.json" on the back of any sites url to determine if they have an API?  I'll be expanding this logic to other betting sites as well.

Comment: The config/app.json was found through dev tools. So you’ll have to check the specific site (I haven’t seen this for other sites). So...are you a White Sox or Red Sox fan?

Comment: But Most of the time, grabbing the data from the api won’t be so complicated as this particular site.

Comment: Thanks Chitown. I'm a White Sox fan....was afraid to mention in case you were a Cubs fan, haha.  Didn't want to lose your help!

Comment: Lol. Nope. White Sox fan as well! Eloy smashing the ball and hopefully Robert can follow.

Comment: And oh by the way, you can look for api with dev tools.

Comment: Indeed.  Could be a fun September/October with everyone back and healthy.  Looking forward to watching the Field of Dreams game tonight.

Comment: Thanks Jason...really appreciate that, and will likely take you up on that offer at some point.  I'm going to spend some time next week diving into what you've fed me already and see if I can apply it to other sites as well (including FanDuel).  Will be in touch if/when I get stuck.  Again, much appreciated...Go Sox.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the html.parser instead of the lxml. Also, try to print your nfl_futures variable to check if you are getting an html page.

If that is the case then check inside the html code if the element(s) that your are looking for exist.

Comment: Thanks Rushil, appreciate the response.  Same result when I use the html.parser.  When I print the nfl_futures variable, I get an html page back, but none of the text, divs, or spans for the information I'm interested are findable in the html code.  I think that tells me that not all of the html for the page loads when you first arrive at the site?

Comment: yup, i tried opening the page and the first thing that we see is a navbar and a loading sign. There must be a way around it but, I unfortunately don't know what it is. Maybe you can find it online.